# height:auto overrides all height styles

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a responsive page with two sections. All elements in right section should be responsive so I used :

```
#rightSection * {max-width:100%;height:auto}
```

however any further height styles are being ignored as you see in the code snippet.

I don't want to use `!important` because I have many inline styles with html codes so I prefer not forcing the styles through CSS. Is there any other way to set heights after `height:auto`?

```css
    #rightSection * {max-width:100%;height:auto}


    .mydiv {
     width:534px;
     height:37px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

```html
<div id="rightSection">
  <div class="mydiv" style="background:#ff0000"></div>
</div>

That Red div is invisible because the height is igonred!
```

Comment: Yes, make your `.mydiv` selector more specific. Perhaps `#rightSection .mydiv`?

Comment: That's why you **never use `id`selectors in CSS**. Just don't do it - it has **no** advantages and **alot of drawbacks**. Remember: ***Never***!

Comment: As soon as you've memorized that, go learn about CSS specificity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code whatever is happening is fine `CSS` means `Cascading Style sheet` that means the last rule applies and that to whichever is more specific. So in your case the first rule has higher specifity than the second rule so `height:auto` is being applied.

Refer link for more details on [Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

So in you code you can make the second role morre specific by different ways which you will come to know from the above link. Below is one such example.

```css
 #rightSection * {max-width:100%;height:auto}


    #rightSection div {
     width:534px;
     height:37px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

```html
<div id="rightSection">
  <div class="mydiv" style="background:#ff0000"></div>
</div>

That Red div is invisible because the height is igonred!
```

**Edit:**
As pointed out by @connexo i would suggest not use `Id` selectors [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084555/why-selecting-by-id-is-not-recommended-in-css) for more details on why.

You can use css classes instead as classes help to make your code more general for example

```css
.outerDiv * {max-width:100%;height:auto}


    .outerDiv .mydiv{
     width:534px;
     height:37px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="mydiv" style="background:#ff0000"></div>
</div>

That Red div is visible now  as the rule is more specific.
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This, while solving the immediate problem, is making things worse, by advising carrying on with using `id` selectors in CSS (which you should absolutely only do if you know totally exactly 110% ***why*** you are using an `id`. And no, 'it's on the element'  is not a valid and aceptable explanation!).

Comment: as i have mentioned that this is one possible solution. There can be many more  that depends which one the question owner prefers and the html layout.

Comment: That is a technically working solution for the problem that was caused by the disease you suggest to keep alive using your cure. **No, this is not a good solution in any way thinkable.**

Comment: And I retracted my -1 vote. To get a +1 vote remove your first suggestion and go deeper into detail why the initially presented solution is bad. Find explanatory help here: http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/ And btw, no need to remove the id from the HTML element. id attributes can be useful for Javascript and page anchor purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```css
    #rightSection * {max-width:100%;height:auto}


    #rightSection .mydiv {
     width:534px;
     height:37px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

```html
<div id="rightSection">
  <div class="mydiv" style="background:#ff0000"></div>
</div>

That Red div is invisible because the height is igonred!
```

Comment: This, while solving the immediate problem, is making things worse.

Comment: @connexo what do you mean ? making it worse ? selector specifity, that's what it's about , is not it ? Or did you read somewhere using ID's might be a bad practice ? but usefull when used as anchor or .... can you explain your comment :)